# Consuming RESTful API in Android

Tags: android, python, mysql, rest, pycharm

I am completely new to Android and I have an API created in Python (with PyCharm) and connected to a MySQL database. How do I consume this API? Are there some basic examples?
I only understood that I have to create an AsyncTask private class to use the doInBackground() function. But I can't understand how to connect all of these dots. Can you give me some help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous libraries for this purpose. Yes the basic method is to use AsyncTask where you deal with network plumbing in `doInBackground` and process the response in `onPostExecute`. But in 2015 you don't have to reinvent the wheel. You can use popular libraries like Google's own [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) or Square's  [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). If the response is JSON then you can use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library to deserialize it.